# Angular 2 New forms API how to validate with a regular expression

Tags: regex, validation, angular, angular2-forms

I have a plunkr here. How can I get the Submit button to be disabled till the dob is in mm/dd/yyyy pattern?

https://plnkr.co/edit/GtPDxw?p=preview

Here's the form

```
 <form [formGroup]="flashyForm">
    <input formControlName="dob" pattern="^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$"  placeholder="Date of Birth">
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!flashyForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I am not have it working yet, but you should put the `pattern` on the `input` (i am just checking it now with `required`) and i also think you are missing `flashyForm.form.valid`

Answer (score 1):

You can try pattern="^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/([0-9]{4})$".
Customize year as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern needs to be a string like

```
pattern="\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}"
```

`^` and `$` are added automatically. I don't remember if `\` need to be escaped as `\\`, but I guess so.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10150

Comment: It also needs to be on the input tag, I guess.

Comment: You're right. Didn't even see that :D That has to be a copy-past error or something.

Comment: @user6123723 have you tried it? Any different behavior or errors?